# How to remove numeric character in my input text?

Tags: python, numbers

I want to remove all numeric input in text. what syntax i have to add? please help...
here's my python code right now

```
from re import compile 
list=compile("(\w[\w']*)").findall(open(raw_input('Input file: '),'r').read().lower())
fileOutput=open(raw_input('Output file: '),'w')
for word in sorted(set(list)):
        print>>fileOutput, word,':', '\t', list.count(word), 'kata'
fileOutput.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`filter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) instead of regular expression:

```
>>> def is_not_digit(s):
...     return not s.isdigit()
...
>>> filter(is_not_digit, 'h3ll0')
'hll'
```

In Python 3.x you have to use `''.join(..)` because `filter` return iterator instead of the same type of value in Python 3.x:

```
''.join(filter(is_not_digit, 'h3ll0'))
```

If you really have to use regular expression:

```
>>> re.sub(r'\d+', '', 'h3ll0')
'hll'
```

---

Complete code:

```
import sys

def is_not_digit(s):
    return not s.isdigit()

def drop_digits(s):
    return filter(is_not_digit, s)


filepath = raw_input('Input file: ')
with open(filepath) as f:
    sys.stdout.writelines(drop_digits(line) for line in f)
```

Comment: what's the differences with 2 codes you gave before? using filter n re.sub

Comment: @vynz5, Both do the same thing.